# Why is $J_n$ not symmetric, for $n\notin\mathbb Z$, while Bessel's equation is still symmetric?

Tags: mathematical-physics, symmetry

Bessel's equation,
$$x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-n^2)y=0,$$
has even parity, regardless of the value of $n$. So a solution of this equation must be even or odd. However, the Bessel functions $J_n$, which are solutions of that equation, have no symmetry when $n$ is not an integer. Why is that?

Comment: The solutions of an equation with definite parity might not have definite parity. For example, $e^{ix}$ solves $y''+y=0$

Comment: Might [math.se] bet better suited for this question?

Comment: From the equation you can only conclude that, if $y=y(x)$ solves the equation then $y_1 := y(-x)$ does, but not the $y_1=y$.